# Prove logical equivalences in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to prove the following:

$\neg\forall xP(x) \equiv \exists x \neg P(x)$.
So I tried to prove $\neg\forall xP(x) \models \exists x \neg P(x)$ and $\exists x \neg P(x) \models \neg\forall xP(x) $.

My work so far:
For $\neg\forall xP(x) \models \exists x \neg P(x)$:
It's enough to prove $\models \neg\forall xP(x) \rightarrow\exists x \neg P(x)$
Suppose $\models \neg(\neg\forall xP(x) \rightarrow\exists x \neg P(x))$, then
1)$\neg\forall xP(x)$
2)$\neg(\exists x \neg P(x)))$
3)$\neg(\neg\forall x \neg \neg P(x))$ (substituting $\exists x$ with $\neg \forall x \neg$
4)$\neg(\neg \forall x P(x))$ (double negative substitution)
and we have a contradiction between 1) and 4), so it must be $\models \neg\forall xP(x) \rightarrow\exists x \neg P(x)$.

I'm not really sure if the proof above is valid.

Comment: Note that in step 2 you are using what you are trying to prove

Comment: Yea, that's what I thought... What can I do, then ?

Comment: For example, to prove that $\neg [(\forall x)P(x)] \implies (\exists x)[\neg P(x)]$, you could do the following: Suppose that $\neg[(\forall x) P(x)]$. So it is not the case that for all $x$, $P(x)$ holds. If $P(x)$ does not hold for all $x$, then there exists some $x$, such that $P(x)$ does not hold. So there is a $x$ such that $\neg P(x)$ holds (this follows by the Law of Excluded Middle). Then $(\exists x)[\neg P(x)]$

Comment: Are the quantifier negation rules in first-order logic derivable?, URL (version: 2017-09-05): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2417220 take a look at this, it may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost every presentation of first-order logic that I have seen, one of the following is provided as an axiom schema or definition of quantification...

$$\forall x.\varphi(x)\equiv\neg\exists x.\neg\varphi(x)\qquad\text{or}\qquad\exists x.\varphi(x)\equiv\neg\forall x.\neg\varphi(x)$$

If you have this axiom, then it is trivial to show that $\neg\forall x.P(x)\equiv\exists x. \neg P(x)$

$$\begin{align}
\quad\forall x.\varphi(x)\equiv\neg\exists x.\neg\varphi(x)&\quad\to\quad\neg\forall x.\varphi(x)\equiv\neg\neg\exists x.\neg\varphi(x)\\
&\quad\to\quad\quad\neg\forall x.\varphi(x)\equiv\exists x.\neg\varphi(x)
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\quad\exists x.\varphi(x)\equiv\neg\forall x.\neg\varphi(x)&\quad\to\quad\exists x.\neg\varphi(x)\equiv\neg\forall x.\neg\neg\varphi(x)\\
&\quad\to\quad\exists x.\neg\varphi(x)\equiv\neg\forall x.\varphi(x)\\
&\quad\to\quad\neg\forall x.\varphi(x)\equiv\exists x.\neg\varphi(x)
\end{align}$$

Instantiate $\varphi$ as $P$, and you have your proof.

If you do not have the stated axiom schema, then you can derive it using natural deduction  (see the [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2417303)) or semantic tableaux (these approaches are equivalent).

---

Since the comments and linked question pretty much cover this, here's a less-standard approach that hopefully offers a bit more insight into the intuition underlying why the equivalence makes sense.

In the finite case, the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ can be defined according to...

$$\forall x.P(x)\equiv\bigwedge_{i\in[n]}P(x_i)\equiv P(x_0)\land P(x_1)\land P(x_2)\land\cdots\land P(x_n)$$

...and...

$$\exists x.P(x)\equiv \bigvee_{i\in[n]}P(x_i)\equiv P(x_0)\lor P(x_1)\lor P(x_2)\lor\cdots\lor P(x_n)$$

By the application of De Morgan's law, we have that...

$$\neg\bigwedge_{i\in[n]}P(x_i)\equiv\bigvee_{i\in[n]}\neg P(x_i)$$

...whence,...

$$\neg\forall x. P(x)\equiv \exists x.\neg P(x)$$

As it so happens, there are consistent, *infinitary* logics, which have an accompanying infinitary De Morgan's law, in which the above can be applied over an infinite domain.