# How/where is this technique generalised and proven for other (standard, first order) logical operations (if possible)? A method of natural deduction.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, book-recommendation, natural-deduction

*Logic is something I am entirely self-taught in. Due to my resulting ignorance, it is difficult for me to search for the right things. Therefore, please excuse me if this has been asked before.*

### The Details:

In [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/8xRqv4JX1Io) by Attic Philosophy, an approach to doing natural deduction proofs is demonstrated but neither proven nor rigorously defined. (It is just an introduction.)

---

Essentially, one works backwards. The example given is a proof of

$$p\to (q\to r)\vdash (s\to p)\to(q\to(s\to r)).$$

We start by assuming $p\to (q\to r)$, leaving a big gap, then writing $(s\to p)\to(q\to(s\to r))$, like so:

$$\begin{array}{|lc}
p\to (q\to r) & \\
\hline
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
(s\to p)\to (q\to (s\to r)). &
\end{array}$$

Then we assume the first bit of the conclusion and do the same thing as above, like so:

$$\begin{array}{|lc}
p\to (q\to r) & \\
\hline
 \rlap{\begin{array}{|lc} s\to p & \\
\hline
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
q\to (s\to r) & 
\end{array}}&\\
(s\to p)\to (q\to (s\to r)). &
\end{array}$$

And again:

$$\begin{array}{|lc}
p\to (q\to r) & \\
\hline
 \rlap{\begin{array}{|lc} s\to p & \\
\hline
\rlap{\begin{array}{|lc}
q & \\
\hline
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
s\to r & \\
 \end{array}}& \\
q\to (s\to r) & 
\end{array}}&\\
(s\to p)\to (q\to (s\to r)). &
\end{array}$$

Once more:

$$\begin{array}{|lc}
p\to (q\to r) & \\
\hline
 \rlap{\begin{array}{|lc} s\to p & \\
\hline
\rlap{\begin{array}{|lc}
q & \\
\hline
\rlap{\begin{array}{|lc}
s & \\
\hline
 & \\
 & \\
r
 \end{array}}& \\
s\to r & \\
 \end{array}}& \\
q\to (s\to r) & 
\end{array}}&\\
(s\to p)\to (q\to (s\to r)). &
\end{array}$$

Now we fill in the gap using all the assumptions we like from above it, like so: because there's an $r$ in the first row, we can use modus ponens using $s$ and $s\to p$, which gives $p$, then again with $p$ and $p\to(q\to r)$ to get $q\to r$, from which we get $r$; this looks like:

$$\begin{array}{|lc}
p\to (q\to r) & \\
\hline
 \rlap{\begin{array}{|lc} s\to p & \\
\hline
\rlap{\begin{array}{|lc}
q & \\
\hline
\rlap{\begin{array}{|lc}
s & \\
\hline
p & \\
q\to r & \\
r
 \end{array}}& \\
s\to r & \\
 \end{array}}& \\
q\to (s\to r) & 
\end{array}}&\\
(s\to p)\to (q\to (s\to r)). &
\end{array}$$

### The Question:

> How/where is this technique generalised and proven for other (standard, first order) logical operations (if possible)?

### Context:

I am familiar with the method of analytic tableaux.

To get an idea of my capabilities, see this question of mine:

[An alternative, formal proof that $(\lnot\forall xPx)\to(\exists y(\lnot Py)).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4506093/104041)

Comment: This is a structure rather particular to the connective $\rightarrow$: it's really iteratively applying the **deduction theorem**, that a proof of $p\rightarrow q$ "is" the same as a derivation of the sequent $p\vdash q$ (or more generally, a $\Gamma$-proof of $p\rightarrow q$ "is" a derivation of the sequent $\Gamma,p\vdash q$). Look at $\wedge$ by contrast: a proof of $a\wedge b$ is basically a proof of $a$ and a proof $b$ appropriately "joined" so you don't get the same "in/out" structure but you do get a kind of "predictable branching." Meanwhile, $\vee$ poses a real subtlety: **choices!**

Comment: Thank you, @NoahSchweber. Where can I read more about this?

Comment: This is essentially the idea behind Gentzen's sequent calculus. I guess [Sara Negri's lectures](http://www.helsinki.fi/~negri/prana.pdf) on proof theory might work as a starting point.

Comment: This overall strategy of using a top-down approach to constructing a proof is something that's supported in many interactive proof assistants.

Comment: If you are looking for a formal investigation, a technique akin to the strategy presented by Attic Philosophy is analysed in a [paper by Mints & Steinert-Threlkeld](https://academic.oup.com/logcom/article/26/1/395/2579500). They use a natural deduction in tree form with sequents, but it's essentially the same thing. Also, they restrict themselves to intuitionistic propositional logic.

Comment: Thank you, @HermógenesOliveira. I like intuitionism!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy of proving a conditional by assuming the antecedent and trying to get to the consequent (i.e. doping a conditional proof) is an excellent strategy.  And there are other strategies:

- If you want to prove $\neg \phi$, try to do a proof by contradiction: assume $\phi$, and see if you can get to a contradiction
- If you want to prove $\phi \land \psi$, try and prove $\phi$ and $\psi$ individually
- If you want to prove $\phi \lor \psi$, try one of the following 3 methods:

1. Maybe there is a fairly easy way to get to $\phi$ or $\psi$ by themselves (unlikely to happen if this is the overall goal of a human-constructed logic problem, but often occurs within a subproof)
2. See if among the statements that you have you have some other disjunction, e.g. $\chi \lor \lambda$, and set up a proof by cases on that one (oftentimes, one of $\chi$ or $\lambda$ will lead to $\phi$, and the other to $\psi$)
3. Try a proof by contradiction: Assuming $\neg (\phi \lor \psi)$, you can go through a set pattern get both $\neg \phi$ and $\neg \psi$ and you may be well on your way to the contradiction you want.

Etc.

In fact, I could lay out a set of rules that, when followed in a certain order as an algorithm, systematically crank out formal proofs for any valid argument, whether in propositional logic or full first-order logic.

However, in order for such an algorithm to be guaranteed to always find a proof there is a cost: the proof it comes up with isn't always the most efficient .. sometimes far from it!

Simple example. Suppose I have two premises, $P$ and $P \to (Q \to (R \to (S \to T)))$, and my goal is $Q \to (R \to (S \to T))$. Strictly following the strategy of proving any conditional using conditional proofs, you'd create a bunch of nested subproofs, but it's obvious that in this case that is not needed at all.

So, in practice, a 'master' of formal proofs will see all of these strategies as *heuristics*: something that *often* works nicely, but that isn't always the fastest or most elegant. And it is experience that will tell them what will work well in what situation.